# How to write a comment on a wiki page?

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to write a comment on ROS wiki pages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187420/how-to-write-a-comment-on-a-wiki-page?/) by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 265 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately MoinMoin doesn't have a built in concept for "comments" or "discussion" like MediaWiki. There are some plugins and the concept of "Supplementation Pages" in MoinMoin, but the ROS wiki does not use them. Which wiki page are you wanting to comment on? Usually if they are associated with a particular package you can just post an issue on that package's wiki or contact the maintainer directly depending on the comment.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1